# Fort zancudo gates

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Why dont the gates at fort zancudo open? I tried testing this out by drawing the security forces to come after me through the gate but they just crashed into it and stocked piled over eachother. They couldent open the gate. This must be a glitch

Answer (score 1):

This is not a glitch. It's intentional.

There are other ways to enter the fort. It's possible to jump over the fence (see videos), land with a helicopter/plane or via parachute.